# Handling chunks of data in mustache.js loop

Tags: javascript, mustache

I guess there is possibly a better way to handle the data on the server or maybe through pagination but I am wondering if there is a way to handle loops in `mustache.js` in chunks straight out of the box ?

I guess I am trying to find similar behavior to what `array_chunk` does to arrays `php`.

I can not find anything in the documentation relating to this.

I am using foundations grid and want to display three(3) columns per row, that is the goal(without having to touch the data on the server).

Thanks in advance!

**mustache template**

```
<script id="feeds-list" type="text/template">

    {{#feeds}} // in chunks of 3 please!   
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
                <div class="panel">
                    {{title}}
                    {{!link}}
                    {{!description}}
                    {{!guid}}
                    {{!enclosure}}
                    {{!pubDate}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
    {{/feeds}}

</script>
```

**for reference**

```
<script>
var SITE_URL = "<?php echo site_url();?>";

(function($){        
    var Feeds = {
        options : {
            cache : false,
            url   : SITE_URL + '/welcome/getData',
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'json'
        },
        init : function(){
            this.doAjax().then(
                $.proxy(this.handleResponse, this),
                $.proxy(this.handleErrors, this)
            );
        },
        doAjax : function(){
            return $.ajax(this.options).promise();
        },
        handleResponse : function(response){

            var template = $("#feeds-list").html();
            var html     = Mustache.to_html(template, $.parseJSON(response));

            $("#feeds").html(html).hide().fadeIn(500);

        },
        handleErrors : function(error){
            switch(error.status)
            {
                case 401:
                    alert('You do not have the proper credentials to access this page');
                break;
            }
        }

    };

    Feeds.init();

}(jQuery));    
</script>
```